# is it possible to have a c# generic method that return different object with same fields?

Tags: c#

I have two identical classes but in different namespaces, is it possible to use a generic method to instantiate and populate one object or the other?

```
namespace ns1{
   //.....

    public class class1{
        private string name;
        public string name{
            set{this.name=value;
        }
    }
}

namespace ns2{
    //....

    public class class2{
        private string name;
        public string name{
            set{this.name=value;
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried something like this, but in this way, the type of T is not recognized like the field "name" because T is an object:

```
class1 cl1 = getMyclass<Class1>("Daniel");

class2 cl2 = getMyclass<Class2>("Daniel");


private T getMyClass<T>(string name) where T : new()
{
    T tclass = new T();
    tclass.name = name;  // ***THIS IS NOT POSSIBLE***

    return tclass;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can introduce and interface

```
public interface INamed
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Your classes should implement this interface

```
public class1: INamed { ...
public class2: INamed { ...
```

And your method should have generic constraint of the interface

```
private T getMyClass<T>(string name) where T : INamed, new() { ...
```

Comment: As stated in my answer, it may not be possible to introduce an interface. For example when the classes from different namespaces are in 3rd-party code.

Answer (score 1):

You can define an interface or base class, implement it in your classes, and use the interface/base class to constrain the generics.

```
interface IHaveName
{
  string Name { get; set;}
}

class Class1 : IHaveName
{
   ...
}

private T getMyClass<T>(string name) where T : new(), IHaveName
```

Answer (score -1):

Solutions with interfaces are probably your best option, but it is possible to do it without introducing an interface (which may not be possible in your case), namely with `dynamic`:

```
private T GetMyClass<T>(string name) where T : new()
{
    dynamic tclass = new T();
    tclass.name = name;
    return tclass;
}
```